# How To Set A RadGrid's Page Size Programmatically Without Triggering A PageSizeChanged Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I'm using a Telerik RadGrid with custom paging. My problem is that when I set the page size manually, the PageSizeChanged event gets fired and throws my code into an infinite loop. As a hack, I created a boolean that is set when the PageSizeChanged event gets fired. How do I set the page size on a RadGrid control without triggering the PageSizeChanged event?

```
private bool PageSizeChanged
{
    get { return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["PageSizeChanged"]); }
    set { ViewState["PageSizeChanged"] = value; }
}

protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!PageSizeChanged)
    {
        PageSizeChanged = true;
        RadGrid1.PageSize = e.NewPageSize;
    }

    PageSizeChanged = false;                        
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
}
```

UPDATE: I have a solution that I like now. I ended up removing the event handler from the invocation list, setting the page size and then adding the event back to the invocation list.

```
protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged(object sender, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.PageSizeChanged -= RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged;
    RadGrid1.PageIndex = 0;
    RadGrid1.PageSize = e.NewPageSize;
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
    RadGrid1.PageSizeChanged += RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this-

```
protected void RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged(object source, GridPageSizeChangedEventArgs e) 
    {                
       RadGrid1.PageSizeChanged-=new GridPageSizeChangedEventHandler(RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged);
       RadGrid1.PageSize =  e.NewPageSize;

      RadGrid1.PageSizeChanged += new GridPageSizeChangedEventHandler(RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged);

      RebindGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged, and assing the page size as -

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageSize = CustomerPageSize;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It led to my update and now I have working code.

Comment: I do not understand why you have RadGrid1_PageSizeChanged. Normally you do not need to assign PageSize inside PageSizeChanged event explicitly. It's why you encounter infinite loop.